# Why don't functions from package A get imported into package B when they recursively call each other?

Tags: perl, recursion, package

I'm trying to use two packages and call functions from one to other, but I've got this error:

Undefined subroutine &module2::method_1_2 called at module2.pm line 20.

Is there any way to call functions from one package to the other one without getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

xabi

exec error:

```
./test.pl
method_1_1
method_2_1
method_2_2
Undefined subroutine &module2::method_1_2 called at module2.pm line 20.
```

Sample code (test.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use module1;
use module2;

method_1_1();
method_2_2();
```

module1.pm

```
package module1;

use strict;

use module2;

require Exporter;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
@ISA     = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT  = qw( method_1_1 method_1_2 );

sub method_1_1
{
   print "method_1_1\n";
   method_2_1();
}

sub method_1_2
{
   print "method_1_2\n";
}

1;
```

module2.pm:

```
package module2;

use strict;

use module1;

require Exporter;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
@ISA     = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT  = qw( method_2_1 method_2_2 );

sub method_2_1
{
   print "method_2_1\n";
}

sub method_2_2
{
   print "method_2_2\n";
   method_1_2();
}

1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the very first thing `module1` does is to `use module2`. That means all of `module2` is read and executed while `module1` is still compiling.

The next thing to happen is that `module2` does `use module1`. Because `module1` has been found and put into `%INC` Perl doesn't execute it again, and just does `module1->import` to fetch the exported symbols.

But of course `module1` has in fact barely started compiling, and `@module1::EXPORT` doesn't even exist, never mind about its two subroutines. That makes `Exporter` import nothing at all into `module2`, so when it comes to make the call `method_1_2()` it knows nothing about it.

The cleanest way to fix this is to do the import *after* the compilation (including all the `use` statements and `BEGIN` blocks) but *before* runtime. Perl's [`INIT` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) is ideal for this, and we can get the code working by changing the modules to the form below. I have shown only `module2` here, as the pattern of calls means this is all that's needed to fix this particular problem, but the general case needs the equivalent change to all cooperating modules.

```
package module2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use module1;
INIT { module1->import }

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT  = qw( method_2_1 method_2_2 );

sub method_2_1 {
   print "method_2_1\n";
}

sub method_2_2 {
   print "method_2_2\n";
   method_1_2();
}

1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you assign to `@EXPORT` after it was already used. The following is copied from [Mini-Tutorial: Mutual Use of Exporting Modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639)

---

[ The need to use this technique is a very strong indicator of a design flaw in your system, but I recognize that the resources are not always available to fix design flaws. ]

If ModA uses ModB, ModB uses ModA, and ModA or ModB imports symbols from the other, one needs to pay attention to code execution order. The best way I've found to avoid problems is to setup Exporter before loading any other module.

```
# ModA.pm

package ModA;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
BEGIN { our @EXPORT_OK = qw( ... ); }

use This;
use ModB;
use That;

...

1;
```

```
# ModB.pm

package ModB;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
BEGIN { our @EXPORT_OK = qw( ... ); }

use This;
use ModA;
use That;

...

1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I am not sure why `method_1_2` isn't being exported into the `module2` namespace, but you can get around this by explicitly referencing the package:

module1.pm

```
package module1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use module2 (); #don't import methods

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT  = qw( method_1_1 method_1_2 );

sub method_1_1
{
   print "method_1_1\n";
   module2::method_2_1();
}

sub method_1_2
{
   print "method_1_2\n";
}

1;
```

module2.pm

```
package module2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use module1 (); #don't import methods

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT  = qw( method_2_1 method_2_2 );

sub method_2_1
{
   print "method_2_1\n";
}

sub method_2_2
{
   print "method_2_2\n";
   module1::method_1_2();
}

1;
```

Okay, I think I see what is going on, but take this with a grain of salt.  The `use` function is effectively a `BEGIN` block and `BEGIN` blocks run as soon as they are parsed, so the code looks like this in execution order.

1. `perl` starts parsing `test.pl`
2. it sees `use module1;` so it loads `module1.pm` and starts parsing it
3. `perl` sees `use module2;` in `module1.pm` so it loads `module2.pm` and starts parsing it
4. At this point, the functions in `module1` do not yet exist, so they can't be imported
5. parsing continues

Something Borodin said tipped me off to the best solution: "@module1::EXPORT doesn't even exist".  The problem here is that the `@EXPORT` variable doesn't exist.  This can be fixed by putting it in a `BEGIN` block:

module1.pm

```
package module1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';
BEGIN {
    our @EXPORT  = qw( method_1_1 method_1_2 );
}

use module2;

sub method_1_1
{
   print "method_1_1\n";
   module2::method_2_1();
}

sub method_1_2
{
   print "method_1_2\n";
}

1;
```

module2.pm

```
package module2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';
BEGIN {
    our @EXPORT  = qw( method_2_1 method_2_2 );
}

use module1;

sub method_2_1
{
   print "method_2_1\n";
}

sub method_2_2
{
   print "method_2_2\n";
   method_1_2();
}

1;
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: I do not believe [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) in `module1` will be honored in any of these cases (and I don't see how they could be since `module2` gets compiled before `module1`, so it can't know the prototypes exist).  This is yet another argument to [never use prototypes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966).

Comment: @Borodin I don't understand your comment. Yes, the calls to require in the modules are not necessary in this specific case (because the script is calling use for both modules), but it safer to have them and they turn into a simple hash lookup, so there is no real penalty.

Comment: The `BEGIN { our @EXPORT = ... }` way doesn't work for me at the moment. I didn't actually expect it to as *nothing* has been declared at that point in `module1` so the stash entries for the subroutines is empty.

Comment: @Chas: I mean that without the `use` calls in `test.pl`, the two modules are first being compiled during INIT so the same race effect happens then instead. You need to compile *everything* and only then do the imports.

Comment: @Borodin It works for me in Perl 5.14.0, which Perl are you using?

Comment: @Chas: I'm on v5.16, but I can believe I've made a coding mistake.

Comment: @Borodin Ah, good point.  If the script hadn't already compiled them it would have been a problem.  I think the `BEGIN { our @EXPORT = ... };` is probably the best solution.  If we can figure out why it isn't working for you.  Try `our @EXPORT; BEGIN { @EXPORT = ... };`

Comment: @Chas: all fixed. I had the `use` statements before the `BEGIN` block instead of after it. I still don't see how the `*module2::method_1_2 = \&module1::method_1_2` import can work if there is no `&module1::method_1_2` yet but I think I don't care right now!

Comment: @amon: It is far from a quirk of Perl. It is common to have to wrestle with declaring/linking/calling things in the right order from two inter-dependent compilation units in pretty much any language. I clearly remember doing it twenty years ago in C and many times since. Only Perl has a proper solution!

Comment: @Borodin I think what is happening is roughly equivalent to `sub foo {}; sub foo { return 1};`.  The first part creates the entry in the package hash, but the second one defines the function.

Comment: @Chas: yes I've done some tests. You can import a subroutine from even a non-existent package like `*mysub  = \&spooky::thing` and then define it just before you call it with `eval 'sub spooky::thing{ print "spookything"}';  mysub();`. Spooky!

Comment: @Borodin, it's called autovivification. `\&nonexistant` is basically `sub nonexistant; \&nonexistant` when `nonexistant` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ikegami: of course it is. I found out only yesterday that taking a reference is one of the operations that can autovivify and I'm not used to it yet. Come to think of it I'm not used to anything but data structures being autovivified! Thanks.

Comment: @Borodin It makes sense when you realize that package variables are stored in `%PACKAGE_NAME::`.