# How to call a subroutine from one perl module to another perl module?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a perl file which makes use of two perl modules A.pm , B.pm.

But in B.pm I need to call a subroutine of A.pm. Even if I give use in A.pm and try to use it I am still getting undefined error.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to say 'use A' at the start of the B.pm file, then call the sub  with A::your_sub_name();

Comment: Post a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hard to tell what you did wrong since you didn't show us, but it's possibly a duplicate of [Why don't functions from package A get imported into package B when they recursively call each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11521584/589924)

Comment: Tip: Don't call your module `B`. There's a core package called that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two elements - first is finding the module. Perl has a 'library' path that you can find by:

```
print join ( "\n", @INC );
```

This is the places where it looks. It will also check the current working directory, but it's a little bit more difficult using a run time relative path - you need to use the `FindBin` module for that.

The second element is importing and exporting the subroutine. By default, if you `use A;` you *won't* import everything into your local name space because... you don't want to accidentally override one of your internal functions. That way lies madness.

So you either:

```
use A qw ( somefunction );
```

Which will 'pull in' that function and define it in your local namespace. The exact behavor of these things can be modified via [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) and setting `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`.

Or refer to it by the 'package path'.

```
A::somefunction(@arguments);
```

This also works for variables, although you will have to scope them with `our` rather than `my`.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Can you please provide a complete end-to-end example using `use A qw ( somefunction );` and explain how a novice Perl user would invoke that function without running up against syntax errors and `undefined function` errors?

Comment: If it works for the OP, and doesn't for you, I'd suggest there's a difference in detail between your scenarios. Your best bet would therefore to be to ask another question (and maybe reference this one, explaining what's different)

Comment: Referring to the package path worked for me.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Undefined error could be because your B.PM is not able to find A.PM. Can you try using

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";
```

or directly using `use lib "$folder containing A.pm"`

Also, I am not clear where are you getting undefined. In your perl script or in your B.PM module ?

Comment: No, that would result in `Can't locate A.pm in @INC`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to directly call a sub (glob) from a perl module (File::Glob::Windows) without import the sub glob as it was clashing with Moose with the error "overwriting a locally defined function with an accessor".

This pointed me in the right direction: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=623567

```
use File::Glob::Windows qw();   # Hide everything

...

File::Glob::Windows::glob(...); # Access sub explicitly
```